# Insert a single HTML page as an article in Joomla

Tags: css, templates, xhtml, joomla

I have a landing page created as a single html file with an external css file and a bunch of jpeg images. It looks fine and everything is good with it. I need to insert this page as an article in Joomla so that it looked the same way as it does now, without broken styles and missing images. It should show all header, footer and sidebar content from Joomla and the landing page as a regular page. What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a blank template for joomla and paste the whole body of your landing page to a joomla article.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, if you are using a totally different stylesheet, you may have better luck if you turn it into a custom template.  Joomla's templating model is tremendously simple and abnormally flexible!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

place the css,scripts,images in the root folder of your website.

path could be

`/css/style.css` or for localhost `/joomla/css/style.css`

`/scripts/script.js` or for localhost `/joomla/scripts/script.js`

`/images/image.jpg` or for localhost `/joomla/images/image.jpg`

copy and paste your html code including the file paths in article editor.

this could be

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />//for css
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/scripts.js"></script>//for javascript
<img src="/images/image.jpg" />//for images
```

use absolute paths for locating your files.

this is irrespective of templates